# How to get index of different characters while comparing two strings in Cobol?

Tags: string, compare, cobol

Let's say there are two strings - PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-1 and PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-2. i want to compare these two string and find out the position where the difference is found.

I tried to handle the scenario something like this way -

```
 PERFORM VARYING N FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL N > 5000                                                                  
    IF PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-1 OF TRANSACTION-RECORD-1(N:1)   
        IS NOT EQUAL TO                                    
       PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-2 OF TRANSACTION-RECORD-2(N:1)  

        MOVE 'Y' TO WS-DIFF-FOUND   
        DISPLAY 'DIFFERENCE FOUND AT POSITION' N
    END-IF
 END-PERFORM
```

Problem with the above code is that perform loop occurs 5000 times and if I need to compare such 10,000 strings so the execution time becomes too high.

Is there any other way to do the same thing which will require lesser execution time.

Comment: Can you, please, Unaccept my answer. It does not answer what we now know about your question, Can you also in the future not ask the same question in multiple places at the same time. It wastes people's time. If you want to continue the question, choose one or another place and provide as full details as possible about the data. If here, that means Editing your question to include the information. All the questions asked here or anywhere else.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Now, @NealB has probably already detailed two things which will help. I'd bet your N is just PIC 9(something). Also look at your data to see if the test of the entire fields will help (if you have a reasonable proportion of matches, it will), as was suggested elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ideas to explore that might reduce the overall run time of your program

The first is to terminate the loop upon finding the first difference. Your current
code will continue to run through the entire variable even after it has been determined
that the variables contain differences. If you only need to know that
there is a difference and where that difference begins you could try the following:

```
 MOVE 'N' TO WS-DIFF-FOUND
 PERFORM VARYING N FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL N > LENGTH OF PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-1
              OR WS-DIFF-FOUND = 'Y'
     IF PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-1 (N:1) <> PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-2
        MOVE 'Y' TO WS-DIFF-FOUND
     END-IF
  END-PERFORM

  IF WS-DIFF-FOUND = 'Y'
     do whatever process you need to do
  END-IF
```

Note in the above I changed the hard coded variable length (5000) to use the actual
declared length of the variable with the `LENGTH OF` special register. This way the loop iterator adjusts "automatically"
if you change variable lengths during future maintenance (one less thing to go wrong).

If the majority of the data you are comparing are in fact equal, differences being a rare exception, then
you might try doing a straight equal comparison on the data items first and then only perform the
character by character test if a difference was found. This might provide some improvement but needs
to be benchmarked to verify if it is in fact an improvement. Some compilers may generate very efficient code to do this sort of
comparison, others won't. Give it a shot...

```
 IF PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-1 = PR-ACT-SOURCE-DETAIL-2
    MOVE 'N' TO WS-DIFF-FOUND
 ELSE
    use the PERFORM VAYRING loop shown above
 END-IF
 IF WS-DIFF-FOUND = 'Y'
 ...
```

The final idea is to look at the declaration of `N` and ensure that you are using the most efficient data type for your compiler. For example if `N` was declared as:

```
 01 N      PIC 9(7).
```

The compiler may not generate very efficient code when incrementing and calculating the appropriate offsets with the above. On the other hand, something like:

```
 01 N      PIC 9(9) BINARY.
```

*May* result in a more efficient loop. It very much depends on the compiler you are using and the options you provide to it. Sometimes these small differences can have a significant impact on program performance.

Comment: On the Mainframe for 5000 I'd use BINARY 9(4) with TRUNC(OPT) (hopefully). There is a performance hit on 9(9) (see the Performance Tuning Guide, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27018287&aid=1). It does look like TS/OP is using a Mainframe...

Comment: @BillWoodger Not all "mainframes" are IBM z/os boxes. The IBM tuning guide is pretty good, but when it comes to tuning a specific programming scenario I find the "fiddle then benchmark" approach works best. I have run across contrary results from what the tuning guide indicates for things like index vs subscript performance on tables. However, as you indicate, unsigned 9(4) BINARY will outperform 9(9) BINARY for Enterprise Cobol under z/os.

Comment: Although true that they are not all z/OS, the postings on ibmmainframesfroum.com are massively z/OS. I think in the last couple of years or so there is one VM and one VSE question. I don't know about VM, but VSE is certainly up to Enterprise COBOL. It's the same "chip" underneath. No, you won't find the performance of index vs subscript being different *from what the Performance Guide says on the subject*. It's been discussed on the COBOL Cafe, so if you want to differ that's a good place to do so :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
PERFORM 
  VARYING N  
   FROM 1 
   BY 1 
     UNTIL ( N GREATER THAN 5000 )
      OR ( byte-field-1 ( N : 1 ) 
          EQUAL TO byte-field-2 ( N : 1 ) )
END-PERFORM

EVALUATE TRUE
  WHEN N GREATER THAN 5000
    match
  WHEN N LESS THAN 5000
    no match
  WHEN OTHER
    IF ( byte-field-1 ( N : 1 ) 
         EQUAL TO byte-field-2 ( N : 1 ) )
        match
    ELSE
        no match
    END-IF
END-WHEN
```

This will stop the search as soon as a mismatch is found.

This will only really help your performance if there are many mismatches in your 10,000 strings.

10,000 * 5,000 is only 50,000,000 - why is that such a big problem?

If you describe your data fully, there may be other solutions.

You should remove the silly qualification, have a good name for N, and a field for the 5000 whose value is checked to the length of the field containing your string.

Do you really have a "string", or is it a lump of data? Strings don't exist in COBOL as in other languages.

Know your data, describe your data, explain why performance is an issue. Which compiler and hardware do you use?

I'm not sure that the Tags string and compare get you much.

Comment: I've to process each value of 'N' whenever a difference found in two strings. In code segment you provided, control will come out of loop whenever first difference is found. For example - if A1 = ASFGHHH and A2 = ASYGHHW, then your code will say difference found at position 3 (value of N=3 i.e. first difference) and  it will skip second difference (N=7). I need to process both N=3 and N=7. 10,000 * 5,000 is only 50,000,000 - this is really a problem. My code is taking too much time to execute. yes this string are lumps of data.

Comment: @user1968150, don't Accept yet! Only Accept when you have something useful. Your code does not come out when it finds a difference. How long are your strings on average? Can they contain embedded spaces? Are they mostly matching, or missing, or how much of each? The more you describe, the more it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your COBOL compiler is tight, what you have is the way strings are compared, byte by byte.  It really depends, as other answers propose, if you want ALL differences or just that the strings are different, and where the first difference lies.

Myself, I would probably let COBOL compare the full strings first and only then go byte-by-byte if they're not equal.  Chances are, the compiler has tighter code for a full string compare than what it gleans from your manual method.

Answer (score 0):

The program below uses two different methods with two variations each:

1. Sequential using PIC 9 as index
2. Sequential using PIC s9 COMP-5 as index
3. Binary search
4. Binary search with less loops

In the worst scenario (difference in the last byte)

- Method 2 is about 1.5 times faster than method 1 due to the use of a native data item
- Method 3 is about 11 times faster than method 1

Notes:

- Binary search is slower than the sequential when the difference is in the first 250 bytes.
- Methods 3 and 4 are equivalent
- Performance may be affected by the implementation of the COBOL runtime.

Compatibility:

- The EXIT PERFORM statement that is defined in ANSI-85.
- COMP-5 is not ANSI (but supported by almost all the compilers) and can be replaced with an usage that represents a BINARY-LONG.

Code:

```
   PROGRAM-ID. COMPSTR.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 N PIC S9(9) COMP-5.
   01 N1 PIC 9(9).
   01 STRLEN PIC S9(9) COMP-5.
   01 CMPLEN PIC S9(9) COMP-5.
   01 CHUNK-BASE-OFFSET PIC S9(9) COMP-5.
   01 CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH PIC S9(9) COMP-5.
   01 CHUNK-OFFSET PIC S9(9) COMP-5.
   01 CHUNK-LENGTH PIC S9(9) COMP-5.
   01 STR1 PIC X(5000).
   01 STR2 PIC X(5000).
   01 WS-DIFF-FOUND PIC X.

   01 DIFF-TIME PIC 9(7)V99 COMP-5.
   01 EMPTY-PERFORM-TIME PIC 9(7)V99 COMP-5.
   78 LOOPS VALUE 10000.
   01 START-TIME.
      03 START-H PIC 99.
      03 START-M PIC 99.
      03 START-S PIC 99.
      03 START-T PIC 99.
   01 END-TIME.
      03 END-H PIC 99.
      03 END-M PIC 99.
      03 END-S PIC 99.
      03 END-T PIC 99.
   01 X PIC X.
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-LOGIC.
       MOVE 5000 TO STRLEN

       ACCEPT START-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM LOOPS TIMES
           PERFORM EMPTY-PERFORM
       END-PERFORM
       ACCEPT END-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM TIME-DIFF
       MOVE DIFF-TIME TO EMPTY-PERFORM-TIME
       DISPLAY "EMPTY-PERFORM: " EMPTY-PERFORM-TIME

       MOVE ALL SPACES TO STR1 STR2
       MOVE "X" TO STR2(5000:1)
       PERFORM TEST-ALL

       MOVE ALL SPACES TO STR1 STR2
       MOVE "X" TO STR2(1:1)
       PERFORM TEST-ALL

       MOVE ALL SPACES TO STR1 STR2
       MOVE "X" TO STR2(2500:1)
       PERFORM TEST-ALL

       MOVE ALL SPACES TO STR1 STR2
       MOVE "X" TO STR2(250:1)
       PERFORM TEST-ALL

       ACCEPT X
       EXIT PROGRAM
       STOP RUN
       .

   TEST-ALL.
       ACCEPT START-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM LOOPS TIMES
           PERFORM COMPARE-1
       END-PERFORM
       ACCEPT END-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM TIME-DIFF
       DISPLAY "COMPARE-1: " DIFF-TIME " DIFFERENCE AT: " N1

       ACCEPT START-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM LOOPS TIMES
           PERFORM COMPARE-2
       END-PERFORM
       ACCEPT END-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM TIME-DIFF
       DISPLAY "COMPARE-2: " DIFF-TIME " DIFFERENCE AT: " N

       ACCEPT START-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM LOOPS TIMES
           PERFORM COMPARE-3
       END-PERFORM
       ACCEPT END-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM TIME-DIFF
       DISPLAY "COMPARE-3: " DIFF-TIME " DIFFERENCE AT: " N

       ACCEPT START-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM LOOPS TIMES
           PERFORM COMPARE-4
       END-PERFORM
       ACCEPT END-TIME FROM TIME
       PERFORM TIME-DIFF
       DISPLAY "COMPARE-4: " DIFF-TIME " DIFFERENCE AT: " N
       .

   EMPTY-PERFORM.
       .

   COMPARE-1.
       PERFORM VARYING N1 FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL N1 > 5000                                                                  
           IF STR1(N1:1) IS NOT EQUAL TO STR2(N1:1)
               MOVE 'Y' TO WS-DIFF-FOUND
               EXIT PERFORM
           END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       .

   COMPARE-2.
       PERFORM VARYING N FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL N > 5000                                                                  
           IF STR1(N:1) IS NOT EQUAL TO STR2(N:1)
               MOVE 'Y' TO WS-DIFF-FOUND
               EXIT PERFORM
           END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       .

   COMPARE-3.
       IF STR1 = STR2
           MOVE 0 TO N
       ELSE
           MOVE 1 TO CMPLEN
           PERFORM UNTIL CMPLEN >= STRLEN
              COMPUTE CMPLEN = CMPLEN * 2
           END-PERFORM
           MOVE 1 TO CHUNK-BASE-OFFSET
           COMPUTE CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH = CMPLEN / 2
           PERFORM UNTIL 1 = 2
               MOVE CHUNK-BASE-OFFSET TO CHUNK-OFFSET
               MOVE CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH TO CHUNK-LENGTH
               PERFORM 2 TIMES
                   IF CHUNK-OFFSET + CHUNK-LENGTH - 1 > STRLEN
                       COMPUTE CHUNK-LENGTH =
                               STRLEN - CHUNK-OFFSET + 1
                   END-IF
                   IF STR1(CHUNK-OFFSET:CHUNK-LENGTH)
                        IS NOT EQUAL TO
                        STR2(CHUNK-OFFSET:CHUNK-LENGTH)
                       MOVE CHUNK-OFFSET TO CHUNK-BASE-OFFSET
                       COMPUTE CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH =
                               CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH / 2
                       EXIT PERFORM
                   ELSE
                       ADD CHUNK-LENGTH TO CHUNK-OFFSET
                   END-IF
               END-PERFORM
               IF CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH = 0
                   EXIT PERFORM
               END-IF
           END-PERFORM
           MOVE CHUNK-OFFSET TO N
       END-IF
       .

   COMPARE-4.
       IF STR1 = STR2
           MOVE 0 TO N
       ELSE
           MOVE 1 TO CMPLEN
           PERFORM UNTIL CMPLEN >= STRLEN
              COMPUTE CMPLEN = CMPLEN * 2
           END-PERFORM
           MOVE 1 TO CHUNK-BASE-OFFSET
           COMPUTE CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH = CMPLEN / 2
           PERFORM UNTIL 1 = 2
               MOVE CHUNK-BASE-OFFSET TO CHUNK-OFFSET
               MOVE CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH TO CHUNK-LENGTH
               PERFORM 2 TIMES
                   IF CHUNK-OFFSET + CHUNK-LENGTH - 1 > STRLEN
                       COMPUTE CHUNK-LENGTH =
                               STRLEN - CHUNK-OFFSET + 1
                   END-IF
                   IF STR1(CHUNK-OFFSET:CHUNK-LENGTH)
                        IS NOT EQUAL TO
                        STR2(CHUNK-OFFSET:CHUNK-LENGTH)
                       MOVE CHUNK-OFFSET TO CHUNK-BASE-OFFSET
                       PERFORM UNTIL CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH <
                                     CHUNK-LENGTH
                           COMPUTE CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH =
                                   CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH / 2
                       END-PERFORM
                       EXIT PERFORM
                   ELSE
                       ADD CHUNK-LENGTH TO CHUNK-OFFSET
                   END-IF
               END-PERFORM
               IF CHUNK-BASE-LENGTH = 0
                   EXIT PERFORM
               END-IF
           END-PERFORM
           MOVE CHUNK-OFFSET TO N
       END-IF
       .

   TIME-DIFF.
       COMPUTE DIFF-TIME = (END-H - START-H) * 3600 +
                           (END-M - START-M) * 60 +
                           (END-S - START-S) +
                           (END-T - START-T) / 100
       .
```

Comment: I just noticed one of your comments... you need all the differences.
The binary search routine can be used again on the rest of the string after each match, by changing the starting offset and length. Choosing the sequential or the binary search is just a matter of the average differences in the strings to be compared.

Comment: EXIT PERFORM is not ANSI 85. TS/OP, who has not really clarified a single thing, has posted the same question on a Mainframe support group. 78-levels do not work in any Mainframe COBOL. Also using clock-time is not so useful, even on a single-user system. COMP-5, especially of that size (not needed) has performance implications on the Mainframe. How would the "binary search" find the *first* (of multiple) difference (our initial interpretation of what was required)? How would it find all differences?

Comment: As you may have noticed, I have no mainframe skills. Maybe I would have avoided answering if I knew that the requirement was for Mainframe. No mention of that in the question.
About EXIT PERFORM, you're right. But I'm sure that there are many alternatives to the EXIT PERFORM. If not, the function can be re-written using the GO TOs. I won't do that ;)
Native variables are usually faster, but I agree that it might not be true on all environments. However, using different USAGEs does not affect the overall functionality of the algorithm. (continues...)

Comment: You may find what USAGE gives you the best performances and use that.
Using the clock time, of course, was a quick and dirty way to have a rough idea of the difference in performance. The 78 level is used just to establish the number of loops for the "performance test". Since each function is performed 10k times, the result is accurate enough to decide what method best suits your needs.
I will post how to use the binary search for the rest of the string tomorrow (it's 9.30pm now), if anyone is interested.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be too critical. I'm annoyed at the TS/OP, not you :-) Certainly interested in the binary search for finding the first of more than one mismatching bytes. Only 21:07 here.